# AWS S3 Bucket Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Can anyone help me to find how to access AWS S3 Bucket resources using client `Access key ID` and `Secret access key`?
Or Is this deprecated AWS API? I find many solutions but all uses `identityPoolId` which is i don't want to use.

Comment: What do you mean by bucket resources? Give an example.

Comment: You may wish to consider using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It has specific commands for Amazon S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can login using 2 ways.**

1. By using credentials within your code.
2. Keep your credentials in a file.

### By using credentials within your code.

```
// credentials object identifying user for authentication
// user must have AWSConnector and AmazonS3FullAccess for 
// this example to work
 AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("YourAccessKeyID", "YourSecretAccessKey");

// create a client connection based on credentials
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

### Keep your credentials in a file:

```
/*
 * Create your credentials file at ~/.aws/credentials (C:\Users\USER_NAME\.aws\credentials for Windows users) 
 * and save the following lines after replacing the underlined values with your own.
 *
 * [default]
 * aws_access_key_id = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID
 * aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
 */

AWSCredentials credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

### For crud operation, you can go through this tutorial: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AmazonS3/S3Sample.java

```
    // Create a bucket
    System.out.println("Creating bucket " + bucketName + "\n");
    s3.createBucket(bucketName);

    /*
     * List the buckets in your account
     */
    System.out.println("Listing buckets");
    for (Bucket bucket : s3.listBuckets()) {
        System.out.println(" - " + bucket.getName());
    }
    /*
     * Delete an object - Unless versioning has been turned on for your bucket,
     * there is no way to undelete an object, so use caution when deleting objects.
     */
    System.out.println("Deleting an object\n");
    s3.deleteObject(bucketName, key);

    /*
     * Delete a bucket - A bucket must be completely empty before it can be
     * deleted, so remember to delete any objects from your buckets before
     * you try to delete them.
     */
    System.out.println("Deleting bucket " + bucketName + "\n");
    s3.deleteBucket(bucketName);
```

### For giving permissions in a specific bucket, please check the picture:

[image]

**Add Permission:**

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::riz-bucket001/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**N.B: This bucket policy make everything in the bucket publicly readable. So be careful to use it. If you use study purpose, then OK. But in business purpose, don't use it.**

Thanks a lot [Michael - sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot)

You can check more policies here as your necessity: [Specifying Permissions in a Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html)

Comment: Whoa -- potentially dangerous advice, here -- that bucket policy make everything in the bucket publicly readable.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for pointing me. I have updated ans and informed that you can use it only study purpose but not in business.